# How to iterate through this object using PUG and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, blockchain

I am trying to make a make a simple blockchain project to exercise nodejs.
I created a blockchain object that is formed of block class and i want to iterate throught this object using pug.

```
app.get('/', function(request, response, next){


    response.render('opetations', {"blockChain":blockChain});

});
```

```
each block in blockChain
   tr
     th(scope='row') block
     td block.index
```

when i coded it like this it iterates just once and it doesnt print the index value.
I think its because of my blockChain object. When i convert it into json it looks like the image attached. I think its because of my objects structure. Can you help me with this issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfvgp.png

I want to iterate through my blockchain object and print the block values on a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `blockchain.blockchain` then.
So try passing it like this:

```
response.render('opetations', {"blockChain":blockChain.blockchain});
```

You also need to output values, check [the docs](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).

It should look like this:

```
each block in blockchain
    table
        tr
            th(scope='row')= block.index
            td= block.data.name
```

Comment: Thank you so much traynor. It solved my problem now i can display the object elements in pug file